# Make 'git diff' ignore ^M

Tags: git, newline, diff, git-diff, carriage-return

In a project where some of the files contain `^M` as newline
separators, diffing these files is apparently impossible, since
`git diff` sees the entire file as just a single line.

How does one `git diff` when comparing the current and previous
versions of a source code file?

Is there an option like "treat `^M` as newline when diffing" ?

```
prompt> git-diff "HEAD^" -- MyFile.as 
diff --git a/myproject/MyFile.as b/myproject/MyFile.as
index be78321..a393ba3 100644
--- a/myproject/MyFile.cpp
+++ b/myproject/MyFile.cpp
@@ -1 +1 @@
-<U+FEFF>import flash.events.MouseEvent;^Mimport mx.controls.*;^Mimport mx.utils.Delegate
\ No newline at end of file
+<U+FEFF>import flash.events.MouseEvent;^Mimport mx.controls.*;^Mimport mx.utils.Delegate
\ No newline at end of file
prompt>
```

---

UPDATE:

I have written a Ruby script that checks out the latest 10 revisions and converts CR to LF.

```ruby
require 'fileutils'

if ARGV.size != 3
  puts "a git-path must be provided"
  puts "a filename must be provided"
  puts "a result-dir must be provided"
  puts "example:"
  puts "ruby gitcrdiff.rb project/dir1/dir2/dir3/ SomeFile.cpp tmp_somefile"
  exit(1)
end

gitpath = ARGV[0]
filename = ARGV[1]
resultdir = ARGV[2]

unless FileTest.exist?(".git")
  puts "this command must be run in the same dir as where .git resides"
  exit(1)
end

if FileTest.exist?(resultdir)
  puts "the result dir must not exist"
  exit(1)
end
FileUtils.mkdir(resultdir)

10.times do |i|
  revision = "^" * i
  cmd = "git show HEAD#{revision}:#{gitpath}#{filename} | tr '\\r' '\\n' > #{resultdir}/#{filename}_rev#{i}"
  puts cmd 
  system cmd
end
```

Comment: you may have wanted to `git diff -b` - I showed this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46265081/58794

Comment: With Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you will have `git diff --ignore-cr-at-eol`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562232/6309).

Comment: @JasonPyeron and for future Googlers: I had to look up that `git diff -b` is identical to `git diff --ignore-space-change`.

Comment: Related: on Linux you can use the command-line utility `dos2unix` (and `unix2dos`) to convert between line-endings.

Comment: git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol
alesub answer below should be the accepted answer.  None of these other fixes work on latest MacOS.  Other fixes *do* seem to work on older Mac OSes.

Answer (score 564, accepted):

[GitHub suggests](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) that you should make sure to only use \n as a newline character in git-handled repos. There's an option to auto-convert:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Of course, this is said to convert crlf to lf, while you want to convert cr to lf. I hope this still works …

And then convert your files:

```
# Remove everything from the index
$ git rm --cached -r .

# Re-add all the deleted files to the index
# You should get lots of messages like: "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in <file>."
$ git diff --cached --name-only -z | xargs -0 git add

# Commit
$ git commit -m "Fix CRLF"
```

core.autocrlf is described on [the man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html).

Comment: ouch.. will I have to do this for every revision of that file?

Comment: No, of course not, once the setting is there, it will silently convert upon commit. If everything works the way I think it does, that is …

Comment: The problem is that I already have some files in the repository that have CRLF endings and others that doesn't. I suspect that Adobe Flash adds CRLF even though I'm using the Mac version. I need to compare against older revisions of these files. Converting line endings starting from now on does not solve the problem with older revisions :-/

Comment: Well … you can write a script and change all the past commits :) It's not pretty, but you can re-write the history of your project. (At the risk of ruining your repo, that is)

Comment: yeah, that is unfortunate. I actually have quite a few repositories and I have never needed to diff CRLF files before. I wish I had known about this option a long time ago. Thank you for enlighten me.

Comment: You're not working with CRLF files here, at least not in the example you posted.  That's an old-style mac file (just uses \r for EOL).  That's why the diff is being shown on one line.  A file using dos EOL would show each line distinctly with a trailing ^M, which you could tell get to handle via `git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol`.

Comment: @jamessan yeah I just realized that too.. some of the files uses only CR and others LF. There are no CRLF involved.  So only the CR files are causing trouble.

Comment: If I may quote my original, unmodified answer: "Of course, this is said to convert crlf to lf, while you want to convert cr to lf. I hope this still works …"

Comment: the git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol thing would work. and of course you can write your own commit-hook that transforms cr to lf.

Comment: I'm trying this, but I keep getting `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF` instead of `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF`, and I'm in Linux. Any idea why? I want all to end with LF, not CRLF!

Comment: @trusktr, it happened the same to me. In linux, with accidental CRLF, use `git config --global core.autocrlf input`, do the steps in this answer(rm, add, commit), and you will get `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.`. Remove the files (because they have the original, wrong CRLF) and checkout them again from the last "Fix CRLF" commit.

Comment: Once the git config setting has been updated, you can also refresh your local copy with `rm .git/index && git reset` command.

Comment: I was working on Windows and now I use Debian Jessie. For me, what the @nes1983 mentioned helped me.

Comment: This doesn't work for files with mixed line endings though.

Comment: Version control is not the place to solve this problem. Changing files on the fly adds even more complexity and even stranger corner cases. git even had to add a core.safecrlf and SAMBA never implemented anything like it. Use the newer cr-at-eol and don't go anywhere autocrlf.

Comment: If you have files that match your git ignore you need to use `git add -f` in xargs

Answer (score 481):

Developing on Windows, I ran into this problem when using `git tfs`.  I solved it this way:

```
git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

This basically tells Git that an end-of-line CR is not an error.  As a result, those annoying `^M` characters no longer appear at the end of lines in `git diff`, `git show`, etc.

It appears to leave other settings as-is; for instance, extra spaces at the end of a line still show as errors (highlighted in red) in the diff.

(Other answers have alluded to this, but the above is exactly how to set the setting.  To set the setting for only one project, omit the `--global`.)

**EDIT**:

After many line-ending travails, I've had the best luck, when working on a .NET team, with these settings:

- NO core.eol setting
- NO core.whitespace setting
- NO core.autocrlf setting
- When running the Git installer for Windows, you'll get these three options:

  - **Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings**  <-- choose this one
  - Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line endings
  - Checkout as-is, commit as-is

If you need to use the whitespace setting, you should probably enable it only on a per-project basis if you need to interact with TFS.  Just omit the `--global`:

```
git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

If you need to remove some core.* settings, the easiest way is to run this command:

```
git config --global -e
```

This opens your global .gitconfig file in a text editor, and you can easily delete the lines you want to remove.  (Or you can put '#' in front of them to comment them out.)

Comment: For those who find this now, it's worth noting that **Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings** auto-sets `core.autocrlf` to `true`

Comment: Note that the line `git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol` would turn off other settings that are default. There are three defaults: blank-at-eol, blank-at-eof and space-before-tab. So to enable cr-at-eol while keeping the others you would need to use `git config --global core.whitespace blank-at-eol,blank-at-eof,space-before-tab,cr-at-eol`.

Comment: For my project (it was checkout out on Windows and I'm viewing it on Linux), `cr-at-eol` got rid of `^M` at the end of lines in `git diff` all right, but GIT still showed those lines as different, although the line ending was the only difference.

Comment: SourceInsight keep pushing the ^M character, and git still shows the difference at line endings. @Zitrax's command is the right answer to my case, git diff show nice and clean output.

Comment: @Zitrax's comment is false; the default value of core.whitespace is "". If you wanted to, say, enable cr-at-eol and disable blank-at-eol, you would need to set core.whitespace to "cr-at-eol -blank-at-eol". See also `git help config`.

Comment: I think git needs a bit more complexity, a few more conflicting settings for end of line. I think git should be *more* concerned about my whitespaces. For example throw an unrelated fatal error and leave the repository in a corrupt state when encountering Mac line endings on a Windows (but not Linux) machine. I mean why would I use a VCS that would mind it's business and let me use whichever line endings I want? I see they're trying, but they should throw in half a dozen more line-ending behaviors, to solve a problem that doesn't exist. They're almost there! Keep it up.

Comment: super valuable. I spent a long time fooling with editor settings in VSCode and Sublime text trying to get them to stop fooling with line-endings.  I finally used a hex-viewer to convince myself that the line-ending on the line I was editing perfectly matched the original version, which let me know the display of the `^M` was coming from git diff behavior and didn't represent an actual change to the line ending.

Comment: `If you need to remove some core.* settings, the easiest way is to run this command: git config --global -e`. similarly, if you need to edit the current repo's settings, use `git config -e`

Answer (score 189):

Try `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol`, or `git diff --ignore-space-change`, or `git diff --ignore-all-space`.

Comment: None of that really affects the character that identifies the newline.

Comment: I also tried with "-w" but no luck, still treats it as a single line. Next project I must remember to never ever get any CR into the source code.

Comment: Just remember git config --global core.autocrlf true, or bug the git folks until they make it default :)

Comment: This solved my problem without having to change my `autocrlf` settings. Thanks!

Comment: grr.. none of the 3 worked for me.  I am using git on Windows 7 on files with \r line separator character

Comment: these flags have no effect for me... still shows ^M as diffs

Comment: @Magnus: these flags are about what Git considers a difference. Their use makes it that Git doesn't show whole file as changed if end-of-line convention changed. This is not an output filter - if there is change, it would be shown with ^M. You can try to either configure `less`, or change Git pager. HTH

Comment: When I diff --stat two branches to see which files have changed, files where ^M is the only difference still appear on the list

Comment: @Magnus: Do you see the difference between `git diff -w --stat` and `git diff --stat`? The former should not show any changes if the difference is only in ^M (i.e. CR LF vs LF).

Comment: OK I see what's happening.  -w --stat and --ignore-all-space --stat yield identical diff results, with an identical file count to a naked --stat.  But I realized that all the files coincidentally ALSO happen to have one or two legitimate diffs mixed in amidst the hundreds of meaningless ^M differences, thus they still appear on the list!  Makes sense really since presumably the Windows user had an actual change to check in when the commit was made.  Thanks Jakub for helping me pinpoint this.

Comment: after using git diff --ignore-space-at-eol , all the irritating line endings changes that wre previosly visible with git diff commands were gone. However, git-diff shows only the way the files differ. During commit i.e git status , one still sees the files with Ctrl-M as a changed file. Under unix, one can change the line ending using dos2unix command. find ./ -name *.* | xargs dos2unix

Comment: Worked great for me, but I was just trying to get diffs that included real code changes and not the added carriage returns.

Comment: Can I use all three flags?

Answer (score 114):

Also see:

```
core.whitespace = cr-at-eol
```

or equivalently,

```
[core]
    whitespace = cr-at-eol
```

where `whitespace` is preceded by a *tab* character.

Comment: Yep, this made the git diff tool (also used in `git show`) stop bugging me about the `^M`s on the changed lines! :)

Comment: for whatever reason this did not work for me.  Tried it both with = and no = sign.  `git diff` still shows ^M characters.

Comment: Two ways to do this: one, add the line above verbatim to your .gitconfig either in .git/config, or in ~/.gitconfig; two, `git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol` (where --global is optional if you just want it on the repo you're on)

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7, although I just put it under `[core]` so I can replace the `core.` prefix with a TAB character.

Comment: This question was above how to hide `^M` in `git diff`, not about how to not put in ^M in the first place. That means the accepted answer of changing `core.autocrlf` is not the best because it silently alters the files without user's confirmation.

Answer (score 68):

## Why do you get these `^M` in your `git diff`?

In my case I was working on a project which was developed in Windows and I used Linux. When I changed some code, I saw `^M` at the end of the lines I added in `git diff`. I think the `^M` were showing up because they were different line endings than the rest of the file. Because the rest of the file was developed in Windows it used `CRLF` line endings, and in Linux it uses `LF` line endings.

Apparently, the Windows developer didn't use the option "*Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings*" during the installation of Git.

## So what should we do about this?

You can have the Windows users reinstall git and use the "*Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings*" option. This is what I would prefer, because I see Windows as an exception in its line ending characters and Windows fixes its own issue this way.

If you go for this option, you should however fix the current files (because they're still using the `CRLF` line endings). I did this by following these steps:

1. Remove all files from the repository, but not from your filesystem.

   ```
    git rm --cached -r .
   ```
2. Add a [`.gitattributes`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-Settostringvalueauto) file that enforces certain files to use a `LF` as line endings. Put this in the file:

   ```
    * text=auto eol=lf
   ```
3. Add all the files again.

   ```
    git add .
   ```

   This will show messages like this:

   ```
    warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in <filename>.
    The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
   ```
4. You could remove the `.gitattributes` file unless you have stubborn Windows users that don't want to use the "*Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings*" option.
5. Commit and push it all.
6. Remove and checkout the applicable files on all the systems where they're used. On the Windows systems, make sure they now use the "*Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings*" option. You should also do this on the system where you executed these tasks because when you added the files git said:

   ```
    The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
   ```

   You can do something like this to remove the files:

   ```
    git ls | grep ".ext$" | xargs rm -f
   ```

   And then this to get them back with the correct line endings:

   ```
    git ls | grep ".ext$" | xargs git checkout
   ```

   Replacing `.ext` with the file extensions you want to match.

Now your project only uses `LF` characters for the line endings, and the nasty `CR` characters won't ever come back :).

The other option is to enforce windows style line endings. You can also use the `.gitattributes` file for this.

More info:
https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-all

Comment: To fix all line endings in a specific file, if using Sublime Text, you can go to `View` -> `Line Endings` and click on `Unix`.

Comment: What exactly does this `^M` means? Is it a windows or linux newline? Or is it just a "different" newline compared to the other newlines in the file?

Comment: Good one, I think it's just a "different" newline (different than most others)

Comment: -1 as reinstalling git to accomplish `git config --global core.autocrlf true` is overkill, and the anti-Windows/anti-`CR` campaign seems tangential to the question.

Comment: should'nt it be `*.ext text eol=lf` inplace of of `crlf` ? I think that was a typo, that noone noticed !

Comment: You state that Windows use CR but actually it use CRLF. Files with CR only at e.o.l. are from mac os 9 and prior. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 58):

> Is there an option like "treat ^M as newline when diffing" ?

There will be one with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), as the "`diff`" family of commands learned to ignore differences in carriage return at the end of line.

See [commit e9282f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9282f02b2f21118f3383608718e38efc3d967e1) (26 Oct 2017) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
Helped-by: [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 10f65c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10f65c239a885336b745cc9d2e1654980ffef41e), 27 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### diff: `--ignore-cr-at-eol`
>
> A new option **`--ignore-cr-at-eol`** tells the diff machinery to treat a carriage-return at the end of a (complete) line as if it does not exist.
>
> Just like other "`--ignore-*`" options to ignore various kinds of whitespace differences, this will help reviewing the real changes you made without getting distracted by spurious `CRLF<->LF` conversion made by your editor program.

Comment: @kaartic Thank you for editing the answer and referencing the right commit!

Comment: Whilst it's generally good practice to set `git config --global core.autocrlf true` as in the accepted answer, this answers the OP's question more directly: 'Is there an option like "treat ^M as newline when diffing" ?'

Comment: As of Git 2.20 this doesn't hide ^M's

Comment: @user1944491 I didn't notice any regression, meaning it sill ignores eol when diffing with this option in Git 2.26.

Comment: @VonC Using this argument in the git diff command didn't work. Nor did setting my core.whitespace value on `git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)` but adding Jason Pyeron's core.pager answer fixed it. YMMV obviously.

Comment: This does not invoke `git config` and benefit people using `git diff --no-index`.

Answer (score 46):

In my case, what did it was this command:

```
git config  core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

Source: https://public-inbox.org/git/8d7e4807-9a79-e357-8265-95f22ab716e0@web.de/T/

Comment: git config  core.whitespace cr-at-eol
this should be the accepted answer.  None of these other fixes work on latest MacOS.  Other fixes *do* seem to work on older Mac OSes.

Comment: I chose to apply it only for my local environment with:

`git config --local core.whitespace cr-at-eol`

I am on macOS Ventura 13.4.1. This suggestion worked well for me. The suggestions given in other comments had no effect.

Answer (score 44):

**TL;DR**

Change the `core.pager` to `"tr -d '\r' | less -REX"`, not the source code

**This is why**

Those pesky ^M shown are an artifact of the colorization and the pager. [image]
It is caused by `less -R`, a default git pager option. (git's default pager is [`less -REX`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less))

The first thing to note is that [`git diff -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) will not show changes in white space (e.g. the \r\n vs \n)

setup:

```
git clone https://github.com/CipherShed/CipherShed
cd CipherShed
```

A quick test to create a unix file and change the line endings will show no changes with `git diff -b`:

```
echo -e 'The quick brown fox\njumped over the lazy\ndogs.' > test.txt
git add test.txt
unix2dos.exe test.txt
git diff -b test.txt
```

We note that forcing a pipe to less does not show the ^M, but enabling color and `less -R` does:

```
git diff origin/v0.7.4.0 origin/v0.7.4.1 | less
git -c color.ui=always diff origin/v0.7.4.0 origin/v0.7.4.1 | less -R
```

The fix is shown by using a pipe to strip the \r (^M) from the output:

```
git diff origin/v0.7.4.0 origin/v0.7.4.1
git -c core.pager="tr -d '\r' | less -REX"  diff origin/v0.7.4.0 origin/v0.7.4.1
```

An unwise alternative is to use `less -r`, because it will pass through all control codes, not just the color codes.

If you want to just edit your git config file directly, this is the entry to update/add:

```
[core]
        pager = tr -d '\\r' | less -REX
```

Comment: I had this problem in a repo where some of the files had `\r\n` line endings and some had `\n` line endings (I don't know if that's relevant); diffs of the former showed the `^M` in the modified lines (that is, the `+` lines). `core.autocrlf` was set to `true`. Running `git config core.pager "tr -d '\r' | less -REX"` got rid of the pesky `^M`s. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the only answer if you must work with differing line endings in your repo(s) -- e.g. you use checkout as-is, commit as-is, purposefully.

Comment: `git diff -b` is what I was looking for, but I do appreciate the thorough explanation.

Comment: Yes!  Of all the answers to this question, modifying the git "config" file's `[core]` section by adding `pager = tr -d '\\r' | less -REX` was the only answer that worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: `git diff -b` did not work, but the config modification did.

Comment: I know we aren't supposed to say thank you, but THANK YOU. This restores some sanity to my `git diff`. May I never see another `^M` again!

Answer (score 14):

I struggled with this problem for a long time. By far the easiest solution is to not worry about the ^M characters and just use a visual diff tool that can handle them.

Instead of typing:

```
git diff <commitHash> <filename>
```

try:

```
git difftool <commitHash> <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I just ran "git difftool" and it basically compared all changed files in a loop

Comment: like, what tool can handle it?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a quick line that makes the `git diff` but does not show the different endings (thus the `^M`) use the one in the first comments to the original question, it worked for me:

```
 git diff -b
```

Take into account that, in the long run, you should get your line endings configuration right, as all other answers suggest.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by VonC, this has already been included in git 2.16+. Unfortunately, the name of the option (`--ignore-cr-at-eol`) differs from the one used by GNU diff that I'm used to (`--strip-trailing-cr`).

When I was confronted with this problem, my solution was to invoke GNU diff instead of git's built-in diff, because my git is older than 2.16. I did that using this command line:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='diff -u --strip-trailing-cr "$2" "$5";true;#' git diff --ext-diff
```

That allows using `--strip-trailing-cr` and any other GNU diff options.

There's also this other way:

```
git difftool -y -x 'diff -u --strip-trailing-cr'
```

but it doesn't use the configured pager settings, which is why I prefer the former.

Answer (score 3):

If the git patch is already generated in a windows machine and you are using it you can format the patch with dos2unix utility in Linux.

```
find -name "*.patch"| xargs dos2unix
```

This will solve the ^M at EOL and you will be able to git apply patch in your linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the `core.autocrlf=true` setting with the `--ignore-space-at-eol` paramerer to ignore line ending changes:

```
git -c "core.autocrlf=true" diff --ignore-space-at-eol
```