# Ignore whitespace when doing a merge in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, whitespace

We're hitting a problem when merging in Mercurial where whitespace changes are causing merge conflicts which mask any "real" conflicts we may have and makes merging a nightmare. We've recently conformed to a formatting style which changed the indentation of files in some branches and merging has become almost impossible since.

As an example, try:

```
hg init testrepo
cd testrepo/

echo "This is text." > newfile.txt
hg add newfile.txt
hg commit -m "Created a file."
hg branch newbranch
echo "This is some more text." > newfile.txt
hg commit -m "Changed text in the file."
hg update default
echo "   This is text." > newfile.txt
hg commit -m "Added indentation whitespace."
```

This results in two branches, one with whitespace changes, the other with textual changes:

```
@  2     "   This is text".
|    
|
| o  1   "This is some more text."
|/     
|
o  0     "This is text."
```

When trying an `hg merge` on this I get a merge conflict. If we have conflicts on every line it becomes difficult and time consuming to sort out the "real" conflicts. What I'd prefer is for the merge process to think "OK, changeset 2 line 1 differs from the parent only in whitespace so consider it unchanged. Pick changeset 1 line 1 as the merged result."

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: Thanks for the note - I wasn't aware of the Go lang and have been reading up on it with interest. Like a sort of Python / Java hybrid.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515597/add-only-non-whitespace-changes/29986651#29986651

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignoring whitespace or not is a choice your merge tool makes.  You can configure all manner of merge tools for use with mercurial as shown here: [MergeToolConfiguration](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration)

Mercurial's internal pre-merge won't/can't ignore whitespace, but if your external merge tool does and it finds only whitespace changes it will exit immediately, and if it finds other that whitespace changes it can hide the whitespace changes when it does load.

For example, with the popular [kdiff3 merge tool](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) you'd enable the "White space 2/3-file merge" setting and tell it whether to pick left or right.

Tl;Dr: turn this on in your merge tool, not in mercurial.

Comment: Thx, I managed to set kdiff3 as the merge tool and set the "White space 2/3-file merge" to "Pick B". Unfortunately it still see's a conflict with the example I gave and therefore still requires manual intervention, even through the change on one side is only whitespace. I think I'll post a new question on merge tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a situation where scrubbing the whitespace would be difficult?  If not, I would write a simple script that scrubs all whitespace before checkin to avoid this.  The downside is that you would lose formatting, but most IDE's can easily restore that for you.

The alternative would be to use a standard formatter before checking in to do the opposite... add white space where it should be.

Comment: We've got a formatter formating the file before checkin. The problem came in when our conventions changed on the indentation and use of spaces / tabs. Files started being committed with the new conventions and merges were done between branches and we got into a big mess. Eventually we ran the formatter on all files across all branches but now have this whitespace issue when trying to merge. There are many files so we wanted to automate the merge as much as possible. Once the merge is done and all history contains the new format all will be well again.