# How can you combine git add patch -p mode with diff's ignore-all-space

Tags: git, whitespace, patch

How can I do git add with patch mode but ignoring whitespace changes.

The use case is for when you've reformatted a file and also made changes to it. I want to commit the real code changes separately first (as shown by git diff -w path) and then commit the reformatting as a separate commit.

Comment: The 'g' option to git add --patch will help; whitespace changes will appear empty in the list of hunks to choose.

Comment: Which version of git is the g option added in?

Comment: It was in 1.6.1-rc1-37, so the first official release with it would have been 1.6.2.  (It is not actually an 'option', but a navigation menu selection that is used when a hunk is displayed.)

Comment: Note that g will not do what I was thinking: I interpreted "whitespace changes" to mean "inserting or deleting blank lines".  'g' will show blank headers for those types of changes, but not for insertion/deletion of whitespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add only non-whitespace changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515597/add-only-non-whitespace-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: This answer is old. 6 years down the road, the other answer by Justin is much better. Prefer to use `git apply --cached`

I suggest simply roundtripping a diff

Idea:

```
git diff --ignore-all-space | (git reset --hard && git apply)
```

**Warning**: this is fraught with danger because of the `git reset` there (it will not preserve changes to binary files as written). Perhaps you'd want a bash function similar to

```
function cleanup_patch()
{
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then 
        echo 'Must provide explicit paths (wildcards allowed)'; 
    else
        git diff --ignore-all-space -- "$@" |
            (git checkout HEAD -- "$@" &&
             git apply)
    fi
}
```

Afaict the seemingly useful `--binary` option to diff doesn't honour the whitespace ignore flags

Comment: I did it by redirecting diff's output to a file. Then using checkout path and finally apply with --ignore-whitespace. If you want to edit your answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Sam: if my answer helped you, that's enough. Why is using a temporary file substantially better? What you describe appears to be exactly what the `cleanup_patch` function does, only with added tedium. I might be missing something

Comment: Well outputting to a file is just safety wheels for when you are not using diff & patch that often. You can check that the patch looks sane and if you screw after reseting/checkouting you can at least manually apply the patches changes. Iow me being a n00b. Anyway don't you at least think checking out a specific path is safer than reseting the whole working dir? Oh now I see your shell function actually does that X_X I'll continue thinking out loud. Shouldn't you use the --ignore-whitespace flag with apply?

Comment: @Sam: ignoring whitespace on apply is redundant. Glad you noticed the `checkout` in the bash function. By all means, use a temp file if you want. My preference would be to `commit`/`reset HEAD^` or use `git stash` if I were doubting it. However, I usually cleanup patches manually anyway

Comment: So why does apply have that flag?

Comment: @Sam: it is there in case you _do_ need it, like all other options really. In this case we're feeding it a diff that ignores all space changes, so I'd consider it a bug if apply could ignore further white space

Comment: `git reset --hard ` will remove your current changes

Comment: @AnkurLoriya that's on purpose but I agree it makes the one liner approach to risky. The other answer should be the accepted answer.  Will add a note at the top in a few minutes

Answer (score 25):

Here's an adaptation from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515597/git-add-only-non-whitespace-changes).

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

It has the benefit that you don't need to use `stash`, temporary files, or perform a `reset --hard` on your working folders.

*Addendum*

The solution above only stages changes except whitespace-only edits.  This did not address patch, though using `--patch` to stage isn't straight forward in this situation.

**Patch Option 1: Edit the diff in a text editor**

There are many ways to implement this using a text editor.  Vim is especially suited to this.

In the root directory of your repository, start Vim.

In normal mode, load the diff into an empty buffer with...

```
:r !git diff -w --no-color
:set ft=diff  # if you want syntax highlighting
```

Edit the diff and remove the parts you don't want to stage.

To stage the contents of the vim buffer, run the vim ex command...

```
:w !git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

If you're a Vim afficionado, you could use visual mode to stage, too!

```
:<',>'w !git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

You can commit the staged changes with the ex command...

```
:!git commit -m "message"
# or
:!git commit
```

Clear the buffer, read the unstaged changes, and repeat

```
:bd! | set ft=diff | r !git diff -w --no-color
```

Eventually, you'll be left with only whitespace changes to commit.

If you don't use Vim, you could also dump `git diff` into a file, edit the file, save, then feed the file into `git apply`.  Commit and repeat until done.  It's a bit tedious, but functional.

**Patch Option 2: Patch reset**

It's backwards from `git add --patch`, but once you've staged non-whitespace changes with...

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

...you can unstage chunks in patch mode with...

```
git reset --patch .
```

Keep in mind you're removing the changes that you want to keep staged.  Repeat and commit as necessary until you only have whitespace changes left.

Comment: Well that's just fabulous.  Very useful after Visual Studio poops all over web.config.

Comment: How does have so many upvotes. It completely fails to include git add --patch, allowing the user to go through all of their changes in hunks, but ignoring whitespace changes?

Comment: I completely overlooked "patch", Chucky.  Updated with some alternatives to your solution.  Thanks!

Comment: This can fail in some complicated cases when the context has whitespace errors that are ignored by git diff.  The unidiff-zero options on diff and apply can help by removing all contexts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904526/5520728

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do git add --patch but ignore all whitespace like the asker is asking, you can do this in one command:

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace && git checkout -- . && git reset && git add -p
```

`git diff -w --no-color` creates a diff

`git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace` applies the diff ignoring whitepace, and indexes it

`git checkout -- .` removes the unindexed “whitespace” changes

`git reset` resets the index to just the non-whitespace changes

`git add -p` adds the non-whitespace changes in patch mode

Wrap this up in an alias, like so:

`alias gwap=“git diff -U0 -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero && git checkout -- . && git reset && git add -p”`

Or if you're on a unix based system like I am:

```
gwap= !git diff -U0 -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero && git checkout -- . && git reset && git add -p
```

(Notice I added options `-U0`, and `--unidiff-zero` respectively to workaround context matching issues, according to [this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515597/add-only-non-whitespace-changes#comment61915463_7149602))

Source: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/696df00135-remove-whitespace-changes-then-git-add-p

Comment: It might also be useful to stash the whitespace changes and then pop them after this command, just for safety. I wasn't sure how to do this without stashing everything in the index. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I don't know of anyway to selectively stash, and I've looked extensively for that ability.  However, this solution works great if your whitespace-only changes are caused by a formatting tool (e.g. `gofmt` or `rustfmt`).  I just rerun the formatting tool after committing to restore the whitespace changes.

Comment: After `git diff | git apply`, maybe `git stash --keep-index` will work to save the whitespace changes.  It'll stash all changes, but leave the index alone.  `git reset && git add -p`, commit until done, then `git stash pop` should restore the whitespace changes.  Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git).

Comment: I gave that a try, Justin. But merge conflicts occur when popping the stash.

Comment: I feared as much. :/  I guess a temp file will have to suffice.  Before `git checkout -- .`, `git diff -U0 --no-color > some-temp-file`, then at the end, `<some-temp-file git apply --cached --unidiff-zero && rm some-temp-file`.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust and versatile version of @"Justin C"s answer is:

```
anw = !git diff -U0 -w --no-color -- \"$@\" | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero "#"
```

- With no argument - adds all tracked files' non-whitespace changes
- Given files/directories - only adds non-whitespace changes in those locations

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487648/5353461) for more.