# Is there a way to show *only* whitespace differences with git diff?

Tags: git, whitespace

I'd like to commit all my whitespace corrections in their own commit, to keep everything else pure from whitespace changes.

It's easy to filter *out* whitespace differences with `git diff` using something like this

```
git diff --ignore-all-space --ignore-space-change --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-blank-lines
```

but how do I get a listing of *only* whitespace differences?

(It would also be useful to get a list of files that *only* have whitespace differences, so I can just `add` them all without going through them with `git add -p` to pick out the whitespace differences.  But I suppose that's secondary.)

Comment: `diff -u <(git diff --stat --ignore-all-space --ignore-space-change --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-blank-lines) <(git diff --stat)` for your second question, maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you could do it:

- Start with a clean working directory (e.g. `git reset --hard`)
- Use [Whitespace Total Fixer](https://github.com/dlenski/wtf) to clean up all the whitespace errors. There are options to fix or ignore various issues but the default may be fine:

  ```
    find . -name "*.whatever_extension_you_need" -exec wtf -v -i {} \;
  ```
- `git diff` will now show only the whitespace changes
- Stage and commit the whitespace-only changes.

(FWIW, I wrote `wtf`; I'm sorry if it seems like shameless self-promotion, but I did write it specifically for situations like this one where a repository repeatedly becomes contaminated with whitespace issues that gum up your commits.)

You can also use `wtf` to simply *check* for whitespace errors rather than in-place fixing of them; this won't affect your files but it will print a (hopefully helpful) message to stderr about the issues it has found.

```bash
> find . -name "*.whatever_extension_you_need" -exec wtf -v {} \; > /dev/null

nightmare.txt LINE 8: WARNING: spaces followed by tabs in whitespace at beginning of line
nightmare.txt:
    CHOPPED 1 lines with trailing space
    CHOPPED 0 blank lines at EOF
    ADDED newline at EOF
    CHANGED 1 line endings which didn't match crlf from first line
    WARNED ABOUT 1 lines with tabs/spaces mix
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with shameless self-promotion in my opinion!  Thanks for writing it and thanks for the answer.  I'll test it when I get a chance.

Comment: best origin story EVER :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this answer will isolate differences in whitespace *errors* (like if only one of the commits mixes tabs and spaces or leaves spaces at the end of a line) but not whitespace differences that are not errors (like if a block of code is indented further on one branch, either because of different editor settings, or because of an additional level of nesting in the code).

Comment: @Dan Lenski - Is @Joshua Goldberg's comment (immediately above) correct?  (An aside: `wtf` looks like a great tool, thanks for making it!)

Comment: Yes, @JoshuaGoldberg's comment is correct. `wtf` will find (and fix!) whitespace _errors_, but it won't find arbitrary whitespace differences.

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily apply the *non*-whitespace differences to the original, or a copy.  Then you can compare using diff or git diff before reverting.

In a repository, you can do something analogous to the suggestions in [Add only non-whitespace changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515597/411282) depending exactly what you're diffing.  Something like:

```
git diff -U0 -w -b --ignore-blank-lines --no-color | git apply --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero -
git diff
```

When I wanted to do this with non-git files and [process substitutions](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection) I used a small [script](https://github.com/joshgold22/diff-whitespace-only/blob/master/diff-whitespace-only.sh) that I wrote to do the same thing with temporary files.