# Git add -patch... but ignore whitespace changes

Tags: css, git, github, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I can't seem to find a good way to use `git add -p` but tell git to ignore all whitespace changes. I don't want to reset my local changes.

The situation: I had all my changes locally, and was grouping them into separate commits. Then I experimented with a minifyer, and overwrote all my css files with their minified version. I tried "un-minifying" everything, but it still messed up the git diff - because there were so many whitespace changes - and I can't seem to get my repo back to a place where I can see the actual changes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore \*all\* whitespace changes with git-diff between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159394/ignore-all-whitespace-changes-with-git-diff-between-commits)

Comment: @MrJLP nah that question is about diffs. This one is about `git add`

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785950/812013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Resetting and readding *(recommended)*

This is the simplest method.
There's no *one-line-straight-forward* way if you don't want to reset and readd in your working directory. You should do exactly that, here's a good way explained step-by-step:

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace && git checkout -- . && git reset && git add -p
```

`git diff -w --no-color` creates a diff without terminal formatting and colors

`git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace` applies the diff ignoring whitepace, and indexes it

`git checkout -- .` removes the unindexed “whitespace” changes

`git reset` resets the index to just the non-whitespace changes

`git add -p` adds the non-whitespace changes in patch mode

([source here](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/696df00135-remove-whitespace-changes-then-git-add-p))

---

### **Without resetting**

This partially answers your problem, without stashing or resetting.
You can "diff and apply" only non-whitespace changes, in a way like this:

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

This is another way, but please notice that patching here is a bit of a mess, you need *to buffer and manually change diff removing whitespaces*.
If you use VIM, here's quick step-by-step commands you can use to bufferize, quickly find, remove and finally apply clean diffs:

`:r !git diff -w --no-color` this creates a new buffer with your diff

`:set ft=diff`  (optional) use this if you want syntax highlighting

now you need to manually remove what you don't want to stage, then

`:w !git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace` to apply current fixed diff

and eventually commit this diff with `:!git commit -m "your fixed commit"`

Here's the first iteration. You need to clear the buffer, read the unstaged changes and repeat:

```
:bd! | set ft=diff | r !git diff -w --no-color
```

keep going and, eventually, you'll be left with only whitespace changes to commit.

**If you don't want to use VIM:**

- dump git diff into a file
- edit the file with your favourite IDE/text editor
- feed the edited file into git apply.
- commit
- repeat until done.

It may not be the fastest way, but it's functional and does the trick if you don't like the first method.

(source and similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571643/how-can-you-combine-git-add-patch-p-mode-with-diffs-ignore-all-space/44785950#44785950))