# Patch fails occasionally when ignoring whitespace

Tags: git

I have serious whitespace issues with Git, but things seem to be OK as long as I run the command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515597/git-add-only-non-whitespace-changes) prior to committing:

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

Sometimes, I get this error:

> error: patch failed: index.php:1
>
> error: index.php: patch does not apply

And the entire patch fails even for the files that it already went though prior to the error. I've tried to copy the contents of the file in question (index.php in this case) into a blank file and discarding the changes, then running the command. It works with the other files, but when I change index.php again and run the command, the same error occurs.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Normalizing whitespace in the entire repository is not an option due to the other contributors.

Comment: Did you tried the general options available under: `git config core.whitespace ...`

Comment: Yes, I've tried disabling all of those but the commit still shows whitespace differences when pushed to GitHub