# Checkout (discard changes) on files with only whitespace/lineending changes

Tags: git

Is there a command/option/filter to discard the changes (via a checkout) on all the modified files whose changes only affect whitespace?

Alternatively, staging only files with non-whitespace changes (including staging their whitespace changes) would be fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could:

- first apply all non-whitespace changes (see "[Git add only non-whitespace changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149602/6309)")

  ```
  git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
  ```
- clean any other changes (see "[How do you discard unstaged changes in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713/6309)")

  ```
  git checkout -- .
  ```

In this solution, the order is important.