# How do I do an equivalent of "git add -p -w"?

Tags: git, whitespace, removing-whitespace

There are about 5 relevant questions on this on SO, but I did not yet find the answer. The closest I have got is with the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149602/1479386).

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

This doesn't work. It will add *all* the changes, but I want to do it per partes. Is there an improved way that also adds the behaviour `-p` flag of `git add`?

Comment: Thanks for edit, I think it should either be "per partes" (Latin) or "by parts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
git diff -w --no-color > patch 
git stash 
patch -p1 < patch
git add -i
```

Comment: Supposedly `git apply` could be used instead of `patch`.