# How to make git diff --ignore-space-change the default

Tags: git, config, git-config

I could probably setup an alias, but it seems like I should be able to set this as an option in the config file, only I don't see anyway to do it.

I only want the `--ignore-space-change` when I'm doing diff, not when I'm doing apply or anything else.  I'm trying to make the diff easier to understand by not cluttering it with with extraneous +/- lines that have no real changes on them.

Comment: care to change the correct answer? :)

Comment: now there's a shortcut `git diff -w` which is a shortcut for  `--ignore-all-space`: _Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none._

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the Git Config manual, there's no such option. Your only option is to make an alias.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: I was thinking that from reading that page too.  I was hoping someone knew a way that just wasn't documented.... oh well.

Comment: @Dogbert -  I have the same issue , only when I perform git add -p <file_name>, any suggestions ?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira That doesn't make it the default.

Comment: there is such option https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054020/1243247

Answer (score 109):

You could use **git alias** or **bash alias** if you are using shell-available OS.

1. **git alias** : Run this command to add alias:

   `git config --global alias.dfw 'diff --ignore-space-change'`

   Here `--ignore-space-change` can be abbreviated to `-w`.

   To use the alias: `git dfw`
2. **bash alias** : Run this command to add bash alias:

   `echo "alias gitdfw='git diff --ignore-space-change'">>~/.profile`

   Open a new terminal and you can directly run `gitdfw` to achieve the same.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it is actually useful with examples rather than 'go to this URL'.

Comment: According to the [current git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), `-b` is the same as `--ignore-space-change`.  It aligns with the Linux `diff` command, where `-w` means `--ignore-all-space`.  It's an important distinction because, for example, the text `a b c` is considered the same as `abc` with the `-w` option; in code, this is unlikely to be what you want, so `-b` is a better option.

Answer (score 15):

Old question (2011), but now there's a shortcut `git diff -w` which stands for  `--ignore-all-space`

> Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.

Answer (score 11):

I'd agree with [Dogbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310033/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-space-change-the-default/7310075#7310075) that it's probably best to just use an alias, but another option is to set the [config option `diff.external`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables) to a wrapper script that calls `diff` with `-b`.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but it's a way to achieve something similar for `apply`.

From `man git-config`:

```
 apply.whitespace
       Tells git apply how to handle whitespaces, in the same way
       as the --whitespace option. See git-apply(1).
```

So open up your `~/.gitconfig` or `./.git/config/` and append

```
[apply]
   whitespace = nowarn
```

It might also not let you commit something that only changes whitespace, but I'm sure you can overrule that with some flags.

Comment: The OP was looking for a way to set the default when doing a `git diff`. This does it for `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

it would be great if this were possible with an option.  but an alias works fairly well.  here are the relevant lines from my .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
    tool = mydiff
[difftool "mydiff"]
    cmd = "colordiff -NuBbwi \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" | less -R"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[alias]
    dt = difftool
```

this assumes using colordiff, which i recommend, giving you an *almost* exact copy of what **git diff** would show, with two differences:

1. the --- line in colordiff is colored differently than the same line in git diff (very minor issue)
2. each file is shown one at a time (annoying issue -- anyone know a fix?)

here's my /etc/colordiffrc:

```
plain=off
newtext=green
oldtext=red
diffstuff=cyan
cvsstuff=red
```

Mac OS X 10.9.2, git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)

(colordiff was obtained from brew)