# git ignore blank lines

Tags: git, diff

I have a code on which I worked with Netbeans. 
Another coder made some small changes to my code, but the problem is that git reports me that many files were edited. 
The other coder editor added some blank lines.

I've found that I have to use `git diff –ignore-space-change`
The question is what can I do that by default in order to not get all files as modified.

[image]

Comment: You cannot just ignore blank lines. The file **was actually changed**, so you need to do smth with this changes.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310033/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-space-change-the-default

Comment: Do you want to ignore blank lines only when reading diffs or always?