# When I saved in Windows 7, git diff shows all the lines with ^M

Tags: git, msysgit

I used Ubuntu to upload a repository to github.

I downloaded to windows 7 and using msysgit. When I saved some files in Windows without any changes.

When I do git status, they are listed as modified.

When I do git diff, all the line has ^M at the end.

What is this ^M and how can I ignore this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

I have autocrlf = false in .gitconfig, because I want to keep lf rather than auto or crlf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use [autocrlf](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) option in git config.

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: why 'git config core.autocrlf true' solve the problem but not 'git config --global core.autocrlf true'?

Comment: --global apply to your system, without '--global' - current repository

Answer (score 3):

The `^M` symbol is the Windows end-of-line encoding.

The following should fix it:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

[Similar question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)