# Git diff not displaying correctly

Tags: git

I am new to using git, and when I use the diff command to see the changes I git something a little different on my screen....

```
ESC[1mdiff --git a/first_file.txt b/first_file.txtESC[m
ESC[1mindex f49d459..3748de6 100644ESC[m
ESC[1m--- a/first_file.txtESC[m
ESC[1m+++ b/first_file.txtESC[m
ESC[36m@@ -1 +1,2 @@ESC[m
ESC[31m-This is the  first fileESC[m
ESC[32m+ESC[mESC[32mThis is the  first file added to my projectESC[m
ESC[41m+ESC[m
```

I am not sure what the "ESC" and the numbers like "1m, 36m" is supposed to mean... Does anyone might know why this is showing?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try disabling color: `git diff --no-color`.

Comment: related question: [When I saved in Windows 7, git diff shows all the lines with ^M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081455/when-i-saved-in-windows-7-git-diff-shows-all-the-lines-with-m)

Answer (score 3):

Never mind guys.. After doing some research I ran the following command and it works perfectly fine!

```
export LESS=-R\ $LESS
```

Comment: setting `git config core.autocrlf true` seems a much better solution

Answer (score 0):

That's [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), commonly used in telnet services for coloring. This means the CLI tool you're using may not support ANSI escape code.