# git format-patch and ^M at EOL

Tags: git, format-patch

I am struggling to create a patch for a file which does contain some ^M at the end of a line.
when I edit the file I don't see the ^M, but the patch created by format-patch does point it out in the patching zone context. So when I try to apply it on a fresh git tree, git am is searching for this ^M at the end of line but doesn't see it; and it results of an error.

any idea or workaround for git format-patch to stop taking this ^M into account ?

Thanks in advance

PS: for the context, I have no write access on this git tree, that's why I need to make patches.

Answer (score 1):

Git indicates the CR of Windows-style lineendings with ^M. These should disappear if you convert the File to Unix-style lineendings.

> One downside of turning off autocrlf is that the output of git diff highlights CR characters (indicated by ^M) as whitespace errors. To turn off this “error”, you can use the core.whitespace setting:

cf. http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/04/06/windows-git-tip-hide-carriage-return-in-diff/ or this StackOverflow Question: [git-diff to ignore ^M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)

Answer (score 0):

git format-patch --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace -1  mychanges.patch

This helped me. You can get a better understanding if you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf/20653073#20653073) .