# GitHub diff for adobe flash .as files

Tags: flash, git, github, adobe, newline

Whenever files are changed in adobe flash cs5.5 it uses a CR (^M) as newlines.  Because of this github sees the whole file as one line, and the diffs don't work.  I have non-technical people working on this project, so I need the diffs to be clean on github.

How can I configure git, github, or flash so the diffs compare by lines and not the entire file?

I've tried the core.whitespace and core.autocrlf fixes to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if a [`.gitattributes` file](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html) declaring those file with a `*.yourext eol=lf` help to get files with the right EOL when they are committed.
(`*.yourext` being all the file with 'your extension', ie the right extension of the files changed in adobe flash cs5.5)

That way, you can influence the EOL of *just* the files you need to get with the right EOL.

If that doesn't work, try to version a script like the one described in "[git-diff to ignore `^M`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)", and ask your users to add in their config a a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728).

[image: content filter driver]

Note that this script won't have the path of those files in parameter, so it must be able to [recognize their content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393) (unless you want to try and convert blindly *all* files)

Comment: The idea is to declare that script as a 'clean' filter script, which will detect the `^M` automatically during a commit.