# Why does Git sometimes generate meaningless merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

Quite frequently during rebases, Git generates a merge conflict like the following:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
}
=======
}
>>>>>>> f192b7c... My commit description here
```

The two sections are, character-for-character, identical.

Is this a known bug? Using version 1.8.2 on OS X.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any whitespace or unprintable characters in one side or the other?

Comment: might be a subtle bug, dont they use hashes - maybe its not accurate in some stray cases. maybe you link to both versions and someone else can try on a different platform. or make a new repo on VM ware ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, this has always been a case of EOL character conflicts - i.e. CR vs LF vs CRLF. You may be using different tools or platforms that produce different line endings, especially if you're working on a team, and especially if you're using both Windows and Linux. Have a look at github's [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings), and [this comprehensive writeup](http://timclem.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) on the old vs. new systems of handling things, and [this SO link about core.whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m/7180812#7180812).