# How to handle usage of different line feeds/EOL in a git repository?

Tags: git, eol

`git` allows `CRLF`, `CR` and `LF` as line feeds/EOL. What is the recommended way to deal with them:

- allow all contributors to use whatever EOL and ignore it in `git`'s `diff` (e.g. with `git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol` as suggested in [git-diff to ignore ^M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)) (which disadvantages?)
- define one line feed to be used for the project, notify all contributors about it in `CONTRIBUTING` or `HACKING` and enforce it by refusing patches which don't comply (more work)
- let everything be converted by `git` by setting `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best CRLF (Carriage Return Line Feed) handling strategy with git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)

Comment: @EdwardThomson my question is not about handling CRLF, but all sorts of line feeds (the set of solutions overlaps, though)

Answer (score 0):

Letting git handle it is the preferred method **most** of the time.

This is because you don't know what platforms you will have people working on your project. Each program also handles line endings differently, Atom Editor uses `LF` always, it doesn't care about the platform it is being ran on.

Due to each OS and program handling the line endings differently, let git handle that stress, and keep on coding!

Comment: So just to make sure, you mean `git config --global core.autocrlf true` and there's no other way to let `git` "handle" it?

Comment: @KarlRichter It ultimately depends on the project. If your project depends on crlf line endings, then forcing it would be ideal (in .gitattributes). Otherwise, just leaving the value at the default instead of globally setting it would be better. Check out this [article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/03/08/git-core-autocrlf-settings-poll-results/).

Answer (score 0):

No.  Don't trust your users to get this right.  They won't, and it's a subtle problem until you get people complaining about weird merge conflicts, strange messages at checkout and status showing files modified when they "haven't been".

Set up a `.gitattributes` for your repository:

```
* text=auto
```