# Reverse git configuration command

Tags: git

I keep on getting these pesky `^M` caret symbols showing up with `git diff`. Note that the files are stored on Linux, but are edited via Windows using a Samba shared network.  Trying to get rid of them, I performed the following per [git-diff to ignore ^M](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889559/1032531):

```
[Michael@devserver .git]$ git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

While the `^M` are no longer displayed, what is worse is `git diff` still shows the line as being different, but the text is identical on both lines since the `^M` is no longer displayed.

How can I reverse `core.whitespace cr-at-eol`?  I thought I would be able to see the changes in git's config file, but not the case.

```
[Michael@devserver .git]$ cat config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@xxx.com:root/projextx.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you used `--global`, the setting is in `~/.gitconfig`, not in `<repository>/.git/config`.
You can also see this using `git config --show-origin -l`.
If you would not have used `--global`, but `--local` (or nothing, as `--local` is the default) it would be in the file you are looking to.

Either remove it from that file, or better use `git config` like `git config --global --unset core.whitespace`.