# Don't display ^M (carriage return) in git grep output

Tags: git, command-line, grep, config, carriage-return

To hide the awful `^M` characters from `git diff`, one has to config:

```
[core]
    whitespace = cr-at-eol
```

But they are still displayed in `git grep` output.
How to solve that?

EDIT -- The grep I'm running is:

```
git grep -i --line-number --break --heading -C 1 <PATTERN>
```

in Cygwin (on Windows) with `less -R` as pager.

Comment: What operating system and terminal emulator are you using?  Are you using a pager, and if so, which one?

Comment: Edited my question to answer yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting this from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46265081/10155936) (which is related to `git diff`),

> Change the core.pager to `"tr -d '\r' | less -REX"`

You can either change this configuration globally like this,

```
git config --global core.pager "tr -d '\r' | less -REX"
```

or just use it once for `git grep`,

```
git -c core.pager="tr -d '\r' | less -REX" grep -i --line-number --break --heading -C 1 <PATTERN>
```

User [Jason Pyeron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58794/jason-pyeron) provides a thorough explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46265081/10155936).

Comment: Crazy to do that, IMHO, while there is a setting for the diff… not followed for the grep part… but that works, thanks!

Comment: Would appreciate if you could address the side question as well - though you've already addressed, and resolved, the initial one!

Comment: And do you know which color is used for highlighting those accents?

Comment: @user3341592, can you provide more details ? what terminal you are using? what is the command being executed ? (`less` displays the non-ASCII characters correctly for me), it would be better if you could open a new question

Comment: OK. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398963/could-git-correctly-display-iso-latin-1-accents-in-a-utf-8-terminal. Thanks!