# Could Git correctly display ISO Latin 1 accents in a UTF-8 terminal?

Tags: git, utf-8, terminal, grep, mintty

Fork from [Don't display ^M (carriage return) in git grep output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325129/dont-display-m-carriage-return-in-git-grep-output)

In my MinTTY (Cygwin on Windows), `git grep` display weird chars instead of accents:

[image]

Upon verification, it seems that the filetype is:

```
ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

While my MinTTY is set up as UTF-8:

```
# Text
Font=Powerline Consolas
FontHeight=9
BoldAsFont=yes
BoldAsColour=yes
AllowBlinking=yes
Locale=C
Charset=UTF-8

# Terminal
Term=xterm-256color
```

Of course, when grepping in files from different repos, we never know in which encoding it is.

Is there a way for Git Grep to behave better?

PS- (Side question) What's the color spec for those accents (here displayed in yellow on blue)?

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/), and generally try to keep one question per question

Comment: I understand, but it's difficult to show the real impression of how it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git grep`, much like `grep`, displays the contents of the file as it would be in the working tree without any transformation.  Unlike `grep`, though, it will pipe it through less.  less honors your environment for locale settings (e.g., the `LC_*` options), and it will render data accordingly.

If your environment is reporting UTF-8 and you have non-UTF-8 data, `less` will encode it as you're seeing here, since usually the alternative is either a replacement character or nothing, which isn't very useful when viewing binary files.

Since `less` *has no clue* what encoding is being used and different encodings will map that same byte to different Unicode characters and hence different UTF-8 sequences, there's no way for it to be automatically converted.  `less` doesn't even know if the file is text or binary.  `file` makes a guess about what kind of text is in the file, but it doesn't know for certain, and in the general case distinguishing between single-byte encodings requires extensive linguistic knowledge.

So your answer is, no, in the general case, this is not possible.

Comment: OK, so you say it's not possible. But is it possible to get the char displayed as arbitrary character, without being outputted over four chars (like `<E0>`) and in colour?

Comment: You can use the environment variable `LESSBINFMT` to control how it's displayed (see `man less`), but it's not going to be possible to display it as, for example, the character `è`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful pointer. At least, it's less visible now...