# Should git change the ending of line? (control+M or ^M at the end of the first line)

Tags: git, github, github-api

I use git to `pull` my code from a windows machine.

When the other developers `pull` the files from the server on their liunx machine they have the `^M` at the end of the first line.

How can make git to take care of this for me?

I mean, `git` should change the ending of line (delete control+M or ^M at the end of the first line) when I push (from my window machine) the code on the server.

Answer (score 26):

This GitHub **[help page](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)** deals with this very specific topic and drives one through the steps to correctly configure your Git configuration.

Basically, if you're working on Mac/Linux, use

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

If you're rather a Windows guy, use

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

**Note**: This will convert your line endings on the fly, while performing a checkout or a commit and ensure that your text files will have LF line endings in your repository while having native line endings in your working directory.

**Note 2**: This will **not** rewrite the history of your repository. Existing commits in the repo will keep their potentially mixed lines endings.

**Note 3**: Ensure that every committer executes this configuration step before their next commit.

An alternative approach, which doesn't involve compelling everyone to change their config, exists. It requires adding a specific file name **.gitattributes** to your repository. More information about his topic in the git official **[gitattributes documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)**.

**Note 4**: Tim Clem, a githubber, published a *very* detailed blog post (**[Mind the End of Your Line](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)**) about line endings, related configuration entries and gitattributes benefits. It's an absolute must read if you're willing to get a good grasp of the concepts, the "why" and the internal machinery.

Comment: Nice job referencing the GitHub help page (I like the way they present some material).  To be even more _meta_, GitHub references [Charles Bailey's answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1511273/320399).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the  `core.autocrlf` to true (see [git-config](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html)).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with GIT it's a problem with how the file was originally created/uploaded and stored.  The best solution is finding an editor that allows you to set the end of line type to unix's.

This seems to have a way to do it on the windows side with GIT, but I think that's a bad way to do it in general

http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/04/06/windows-git-tip-hide-carriage-return-in-diff/