# Checking out curl with git results in modified files which I cannot revert

Tags: git

When I checkout curl like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/bagder/curl.git
```

I get (without doing anything) 2 modified files:

```
> git status
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   winbuild/Makefile.msvc.names
    modified:   winbuild/MakefileBuild.vc

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Even when I try to checkout these files like this:

```
git checkout winbuild/Makefile.msvc.names
```

they are still modified. A call to `git diff -R` shows that it may be related to line endings, because the diff shows that `^M` is appended to each line.

Since it is suggested in the comments, that the problem is related to the `.gitattributes` file, here it is:

```
*.dsw -crlf
buildconf eol=lf
configure.ac eol=lf
*.m4 eol=lf
*.in eol=lf
```

Removing my gitconfig does not change the situation, so I guess it is not related to that.

I am on ubuntu linux by the way.

Comment: Are you using Linux? It's probably a line ending problem. Check `git diff -R` and see if these files are being replaced with [^M at the end of each line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822849/what-are-these-ms-that-keep-showing-up-in-my-files-in-emacs). I expect the [.gitattributes](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) of this repo need to be fixed up.

Comment: @hinerm You seem to be right. I added the relevant information to the question, but I still do not know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a second `.gitattributes` file in the `winbuild`, that reads:

```
MakefileBuild.vc eol=crlf
Makefile.msvc.names eol=crlf
Makefile.vc eol=crlf
```

This lines cause windows-style line endings to be used.

One way of fixing this problem is removing `.gitattributes` and checking this in to git. Of cause, this removes the original intention of the file.