# Adding private git repo via cPanel

Tags: git, github, cpanel

I'm trying to add a private git repo onto cPanel but have ran into permission issues and not sure where I'm going wrong

I have generated the SSH keys in cPanel at the 'SSH Access' section. I then added the key onto the private repo in git at the 'Deploy keys' section.

But when I try to clone the repo on cPanel I get the error:

> Error: “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128”
>   when it ended: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
>   from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access
>   rights and the repository exists.

I'm trying to clone with SSH `git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git`

Have I done something wrong or missed a step?

Answer (score 18):

CLONE GITHUB REPOSITORY TO CPANEL STEPS

steps 1. Cpanel -> SSH Access -> Generate New Key(without enter pasword)->after generated key go to under public key-> manage-> authorize (make authoize) -> back, now view/download-> copy key

Step 2.  Go Github-> https://github.com// -> Settings(repository setting) ->Deploy Keys (rights side)-> add deploy key (give title,and add key)-> done

Step 3. Go to Cpanel ->  Git™ Version Control -> clone url : git@github.com:/<private_repository_name>.git

```
 git@github.com:<user_name>/<repository_name>.git
```

-> give_repository_path

-> give_ repository_name

-> create

Step 4. manage repository from list-> Manage  -> pull or deploy from Github -> Click on Update from Remote: works perfectly(any files edit or delete you fetch/pull from GitHub now)

Comment: I'm trying to clone a repository from GitLab and i keep getting the same error as the OP. What version of cPanel do you use? I have version 84.0.14 and it does not let me generate a key without entering a password. Do you know if a misconfigured firewall on the server could result in this error?

Comment: I am using inmotion hosting, please ask hosting owner customer help they will give permission

Comment: My problem was caused by the way cPanel generates ssl keys. When you create a key cPanel forces you to insert a passphrase. GitLab is not compatible with such a key apparently. The solution was to create the key on the local machine and import it to cPanel. Passphrases are for extra security when the key is stolen.

Comment: Well i followed same, it said:
`Error: (XID 68e9nh) “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128” when it ended: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`
Edit: This was happening because i was adding this in my profile being unawared that it must be added in organization if the repository belongs to it (which is ofc not free)

Comment: Error: (XID zndzdp) “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128” when it ended: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Yeah no passpharse works. sweet.

Answer (score 8):

did you get to the bottom of this I was experiencing the same after removing the pass phrase from the key it worked

Comment: This fixed it! I generated a new ssh key without a passphrase and now I'm able to clone from within the cPanel interface. I recommend SSHing into your cPanel server then switch to the cPanel user and do some testing from the command line otherwise it's infuriating trying to debug form the cPanel Interface. Anyway, mark this as the answer! It fixes the issue.

Comment: This fixes it! Just generate the SSH key via the command line without a passphrase. Don't forget to authorize it via cPanel and it works fine.

Comment: Yes! Right, I did the same things and it's works charm!

Comment: steps 1. Cpanel -> SSH Access -> Generate New Key(without enter pasword)->after generated key go to under public key-> manage-> authorize -> back, now view/download-> copy key

Comment: Step 2.  Go Github-> https://github.com/<username>/<repository>  -> Settings ->Deploy Keys (rights side)-> add deploy key-> done

Comment: Step 3. Go to Cpanel ->  Git™ Version Control -> clone url : git@github.com:<usernname>/<private repositoryname>.git    -> give repository path -> give repository name  -> create

Comment: Step 4. manage repository from list-> Manage  -> pull or deploy from github : works perfectely

Comment: Just thinking about isn't this will be dangerous to not use a passphrase, while generating the keys?

Answer (score 7):

After many hours i find this solution and it solved

My problem was caused by the way cPanel generates ssl keys. When you create a key cPanel, forced you to insert a passphrase. But GitLab is not compatible with such a key apparently.

The **solution** was to create the key on the local machine and import it to cPanel. Passphrases are for extra security when the key is stolen

as @vladmacovi said and i test it in my cpanel and its work

1- login to cpanel and gitlab

2- goto https://gitlab.com/profile/keys

3- Paste your public SSH key, which is usually contained in the file '~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub' or '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' and begins with 'ssh-ed25519' or 'ssh-rsa'. Don't use your private SSH key.

4- create a key with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "your.email@gmail.com"
```

5- this command create pub file and ppk file so you can open content of pub file.

6- goto cpanel /frontend/paper_lantern/version_control/index.html#/list/

create a new git repo then click on ssh then from: /frontend/paper_lantern/telnet/index.html

like this picture:

[image: gitlab cpanel ci cd connect with ssh]

7- cleck on import key from : /frontend/paper_lantern/telnet/keys/importkey.html

then paste your key

> please dont type anything in Passphrase box

8- then click on import button then authorized it

9- configure git form like this picture

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**no SSH key WAY**

My repository belongs to my organization and I followed Ghanshyam Nakiya answer but the Error was not fixed.

So I decide to Generate an access token to clone the git repository:

***WARNING: this method has Some Risks like access-token leaks So do it at your own risk***

1. Open your personal profile settings on Github
2. Find and open Developer Settings like the image below:

[image]

3. Open Personal access tokens and generate a new token **(with no time limit)**:

[image]

4. Copy your token at the first Git Repo URL like this:

   https://YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN@github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
5. Now you can use this URL to put on Clone URL field on Cpanel and clone:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was following the Official cPanel tutorial and got stuck with the `reported error code “128” when it ended: Permission denied (publickey)` error when trying to clone a private repository from Github.

This blog helped me out https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757. Specially the part where it indicates that Github requires you to use SSH keys with `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` names respectively.

Comment: If you edit your answer to also mention using no passphrase, then it should be the chosen answer, as it full solved it for me. i.e. 1) Don't change default names. 2) Don't use passphrases. Of course, this means one can only connect to a single private repository.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Through github/ftp auto upload private repositoy to cpanel**

GIthub Private repository with Cpanel Uploading step with one commit command from local pc repository to github and cpanel both

1. create git repository in github (https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/create-a-repo)
2. after create an directory in local with github setup as following command

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "commit"
   git remote add origin
   git push
   ```

step 1. create FTP account into cpanel

step 2. in Github Go to your private repository on GitHub, click on **SETTINGS**, then click on **SECRETS** to add your FTP account username, password and server IP

step 3. On the SECRETS tab, click the **NEW REPOSITORY SECRET** BUTTON on the right hand side, to add a new secret

step 4. Add the details as follows (Using your own details)

The names should be **FTP_SERVER, FTP_USERNAME,FTP_PASSWORD**

and the values should be your own secret details respectively and click the ADD SECRET BUTTON

The next step is to create a GitHub action workflow; The GitHub actions take place on the GitHub server.

In your GitHub repo, click on **ACTIONS**

Step 5. Click **NEW WORKFLOW**, You can choose a **workflow template** but for the sake of this tutorial, we will be creating our own workflow.

Click on any template (I selected the first template), then edit the configuration (“yaml” configuration file)

Step 6. Change the file name to your own choice. (I changed mine to **deployCpanel.yml**), make sure it has the .yml file extension

step 7. Place the below configuration code in the file

```
   name: Publish Website to CPanel
   on:
     push:
        branches:
           - master
        jobs:
            FTP-Deploy-Action:
            name: FTP-Deploy-Action
            runs-on: ubuntu-latest
            steps:
                - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
                 with:
                 fetch-depth: 2
                   - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
                 uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
                 with:
                    ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
                    ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
                    ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

Make sure you change the branch where you want your codes to be deployed from, in my case I am deploying from master branch

Step 8 . Once you are done, click on **START COMMIT** button on the right hand side

This will automatically create a **/.github/workflows/directory** and places the configuration file in it.

Anytime you push your codes to the master branch, it **automatically** **deploys to cPanel via your FTP account**.

Comment: This is excellent, but when I pasted the configuration into GitHub, I'm getting an error on "jobs:" that it is an unknown key. Maybe it is out-of-date?

Comment: I think the script from Sam Kirkland may have been updated since this post was made: https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

Answer (score 2):

Try this method.
open `Tarminal` from Cpanel;

run below command to generate new ssh-key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your github email"
```

Goto .ssh folder in your File Root, Edit id_rsa.pub and copy the content

login to github goto **setting** --> **Deploy key** --> **add deploy keys** --> paste the copied content.

and then run the below command

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

if it return this `Hi username/reponame You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` you're ready go.

Answer (score 2):

No of the above answers worked for me, I still had the error:

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists`

By debugging with the command `ssh -T git@github.com`, I had this error:

`ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.`

I coudl resolve it and fix my problem by regenerating a correct SSH certificated accepted by github with this command:

`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "email@host"` without passphrase

Answer (score 1):

I have found an issue with the SSH key import within cPanel, when I import a private key via the cPanel SSH Key web interface it creates the file but includes the characters `^M` as line breaks.

When I edited the file via SSH and copied the original key from my desktop the Git operation via cPanel worked straight away.

## Solution

Edit the private key after import and ensure there are no [line-ending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822849/what-are-these-ms-that-keep-showing-up-in-my-files-in-emacs) or other stray characters.

Comment: Hurray! This actually worked! So copy paste SSH key texts directly is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem remains, even doing all the steps of the different answers:

- I created a publicKey with and without a password, either via Cpanel or locally
- Keeps returning message "128" from the OP

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem with @nodachi, already did all the previous solution given above.

the problem is the "private" repository in github. When i change my repo into "public", and then create repository again in my cpanel, it works.

i dont know why, the SSH access should be allowed to access the private repo on github, but it wont give the access.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel will not let you create key without password so you have to choices:

1. Using ssh:

- Step 1 create new ssh key using this command

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "cpanel username"

- Step 2 go to ssh management in your Cpanel then manage the newly generated key and authorize it.
- Step 3 go to Github -> repo settings -> Deploy keys -> add you key and enjoy.

2. You can import already generated key from you machine without using password and apply step 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the interface This guide is really complete and helped me fix it using the terminal

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/

*Previous: You must have enabled advanced>Terminal (shell?) Otherwise contact your hosting provider and asked for it
[image]

*Create the ssh_key with NO passphrase just press Enter(replace repo with your repo name, username with your cpanel user and example.com with your cpanel main domain)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/repo -b 4096 -C "username@example.com"
```

*Doesn't say so but neccesary: Authorize public ssh_key generated in SSH access > manage ssh keys > manage

[image]
[image]

Click "authorize"
[image]

*Copy public ssh key found in "view/download"

[image]

*I was using github so if you too, go to general settings

[image]
[image]

[image]

Name it as you want too and paste the complete public ssh key

*Now test it (replace repo with your repo name)

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/repo -T git@github.com
```

If a question (yes/no) about different fingerprints is raised write yes. This will add github to a known hosts file
[image]

If everything's correct, confirm the greeting
[image]

*I have multiple repositories (even if you currently don't, it's most likely to happen) so

domains > list domains
[image]

click home icon
[image]

show hidden folders at the top right hand corner settings>show hidden files
[image]

[image]

inside .ssh folder, create a config file (extension isn't needed)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Write this for each repo you need(again, replace "repo" with your repo name and "home/user" with your root path -in my case home/cpanelUser-)

```
Host github.com-repo
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/repo
```

*Fiiiiinally, clone the repo (replace "repo" with your repo name and "user" with your GITHUB user this time)

```
git clone git@github.com-repo:user/repo.git
```

Now, it should be done

[image]

Took me all afternoon and night :/ If you find how to auto deploy please comment

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while generating the ssh key from Cpanel's terminal I was putting the wrong URL for the site. In this command: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/repo -b 4096 -C "username@example.com"` I was dropping the [www.sitename.come](http://www.sitename.come) and was writing sitename.com, that was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. from cpanel Terminal run this command:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C ""`

2. from cpanel SSH Access:  View/Download  Public Keys  named  `id_rsa`
3. https://github.com/username/private-repo/settings/keys click `Add Deploy key`
4. back to cpanel Git Version Control click `Create` then **Clone URL** `git@github.com:user-name/private-repo.git`
   **Repository Path** where you like to clone on cpanel

Answer (score 0):

After trying various solutions, here's what finally worked for me:

1. **Accessing cPanel SSH Terminal:**

   - Log in to cPanel via SSH terminal. You can do this either through your local terminal or the cPanel terminal. I prefer the local terminal for its speed and comfort.
2. **Checking OpenSSH Version:**

   - Run `ssh -V` to check your cPanel's OpenSSH version. If it's below 7.2, you might encounter issues with GitHub due to recent changes. More details [here](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#:%7E:text=If%20you%E2%80%99re%20running%20Git%20from%20the%20command%20line%20and%20using%20OpenSSH%2C%20make%20sure%20that%20you%E2%80%99re%20using%20OpenSSH%207.2%20or%20newer%2C%20which%20you%20can%20verify%20with%20ssh%20%2DV.%20You).
3. **Generating Keys with New Algorithm:**

   - For future-proofing, use the new ECDSA & ED25519 algorithm introduced by GitHub. [See more](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#new-host-keys)  Run:

     ```bash
     ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C “email@example.com”
     ```

     Note: Don't use a passphrase.
4. **Filename Consideration:**

   - GitHub expects the filenames to be "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub." Changing your generated keys to these names resolved my connection issues. *Strange and confusing though, because the algorithm is ecdsa and not rsa. But its just a filename, i hope you understand*
5. **Authorizing Public Key:**

   - On cPanel, go to the SSH keys page and "**Authorize**" the public key.
6. **Adding Deploy Key on GitHub:**

   - In your GitHub repository, navigate to **Settings -> Deploy keys** and add the generated key.
7. **Test** `ssh -T git@github.com`. You'd see something like: `Hi username/repo-name You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
8. **Clone Repository in cPanel:**

   - Now, try cloning your repository again from the cPanel page. It worked for both public/private repositories

I hope this straightforward guide works for you!