# How can i remove ^M character which is showing in my file on git

Tags: git

after pushing the code on my git repository there is ^M character showing after end of the each line in the file.How can i remove these character from there.

here is the screenshot of the code which is on git
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T3A5.png

i used few solutions suggested by others like--

git config --global core.autocrlf true

git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol

these solutions is not helpful for me.If you have any other way to resolve it please suggest me for that.

Comment: Don't use Windows. Add a prehook script to remove `\r` from the files (on Windows). Best of luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these ^M's that keep showing up in my files in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822849/what-are-these-ms-that-keep-showing-up-in-my-files-in-emacs)

Comment: @sanjeevRm I suspect that many developers don't even know what "emacs" is these days.  The title of that question is not conducive to following through in the context of a Git problem.

Comment: This is probably the best existing answer: [What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)

Answer (score 0):

Git has this "feature" of auto-converting line endings for your local platform.   Some of my projects build files for both Windows and Unix platforms - those outputs need to be correct for their targets, irrespective of what platform is doing the build.  Therefore I prefer to prevent it from doing any conversion and have the files always unchanged.   Modern text editors can render different line endings without a problem and I don't want my version control messing with my files.

**You need to do all of the following steps:**

First, the line-end changing behaviour must be disabled with:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf=false
```

Second, to keep the files correct in future (and before you check-in the "fixed" files), check-in a `.gitattributes` file in the root of your project something like this:

```
*.bat           text eol=crlf
*.cmd           text eol=crlf
*.properties    text eol=lf
*.pl            text eol=lf
*.py            text eol=lf
```

Finally, you need to fix the incorrect local files.  Convert the line endings to LF with:

```
dos2unix filename
```

or to CRLF with

```
unix2dos filename
```

(use the git-bash shell if on windows).  Then check them in.

Comment: git config --global core.autocrlf=false  its not working

Comment: thanks it works for me -- putting .gitattributes file in the root of my project is solved my problem

Comment: @RaviKumar yes the `git config` is just the first part - to prevent future changes; you need to do all the steps above.   Please upvote & accept if it works for you