# Command not found error while shell scripting

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I'm trying to execute the program as followed.

```
./chExt1.sh cpp test.CPP
```

This should rename ***test.CPP*** to ***test.cpp*** but I don't even think this script is executing at all.
I am consistently getting this "`command not found error`".
The script is below :

```
#!/bin/sh
newExtension=$1;
oldFile=$2;

        firstPart=`echo $oldFile | sed  's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
    newName="$firstPart.$newExtension";

#echo $oldFile
#echo $newName
mv "$oldFile" "$newName"
#echo "$oldFile"
#echo "$firstPart"
#echo "$newName"
```

Comment: It is working to me on Ubuntu 12.0. What about your `echo`, do they show proper data when uncommented?

Comment: It worked in Fuduntu 2013.2. Do you have `sed` installed? What Linux OS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried sh chExt1.sh cpp test.CPP? Instead of ./chExt1.sh...

Comment: I'mn using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS I haven't tried running with them uncommented but I'll check that out.

Comment: When i try the method "sh chExt1.sh cpp test.CPP" I get a bunch of not found errors on the script and I have the permissions set correctly we were told to just run chmod 777 for this assignment.

Comment: add -x to your #! line to output script execution to stdout. `#!/bin/sh -x`  It really helps with troubleshooting..you can see what is going on while it executes.

Comment: What if you try a basic `echo "hello" | sed 's/hello/bye/'`? Does it work? (to check if sed is ok)

Comment: Did you try this on the command line first? You are also missing a semi-colon. Meaning execute this on the command-line: `echo oldFileName | sed  's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`

Comment: @DiamonW can you post the output of `/bin/sh -c "echo $PATH"`

Comment: If I created this using a text editor on windows and transferred it over to linux via ftp and then just redirected the contents of the file into .sh files would that cause issues?

Comment: @Alex, I was going to suggest the same thing, it seems like something is wrong with the $PATH since he is getting command not found errors and he is executing without sh.

Comment: @DiamonW: Open the file in `vi` and look for `^M` at the end of the lines.

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: @DiamonW I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands

Comment: It showed the that ^M commands weren't being found back when I added
-x to the output script execution.

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed the issue. Something went horribly wrong when I FTP'd the text file which contained the script and then just transferred it inside of a .sh in linux. I wrote in from scratch in emacs and that cleared everything up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, do this in `vi` to remove the extra control characters. I have had this problem before when editing files in `gedit` or when editing in Windows and then using on a Unix/Linux machine.

To remove the `^M` characters at the end of all lines in `vi`, use:

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

The `^v` is a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> character and `^m` is a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. When you type this, it will look like this:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

In UNIX, you can escape a control character by preceeding it with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. The `:%s` is a basic search and replace command in vi. It tells `vi` to replace the regular expression between the first and second slashes (`^M`) with the text between the second and third slashes (nothing in this case). The `g` at the end directs `vi` to search and replace globally (all occurrences).

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/)

Comment: Is there an emacs equivalent of this? I haven't had to learn vi at all this semester so I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: If you don't know `vi`, then type `vi filename` at the command line, then type the command just as shown (colon and everything). Then to save, type `SHIFT+Z+Z` (do not press the + sign). Or you can type `:wq!`

Comment: see also this SO question for emacs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171609/in-emacs-how-to-strip-cr-m-and-leave-lf-j-characters

Comment: or this http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/consultdev/answers/dialup/other_clean_ctrl_m.html

Comment: It's saying that pattern ^M isn't found.